# Salesforce - Access Case Records even if you don't have 'View All' case access

Tags: java, salesforce, apex

I'm having a hard time in Apex Class wherein I'm unable to get Case Count of a specific record type. Reason behind is that user has no 'View All' case access so he's unable to view cases that is not assigned to him. As per our client, they don't want to their users to have View All case access.

Below is my apex code

```
    public String curPage = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');  

    Object__c getRecord = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Object__c  WHERE Id = :curPage];
    system.debug('getRecord ' + getRecord);

    RecordType getRecordType = [SELECT id, name from RecordType WHERE Name = 'Sample Case'];
    system.debug('getRecordType ' + getRecordType);

    getCaseCount = [SELECT count() From Case where PSOFT_Project_Request__r.Id =: getRecord.Id and RecordTypeId =: getRecordType.Id];
    system.debug('getCaseCount ' + getCaseCount );
```

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce doesn't allow sharing without the correct permissions. Have you considered or tried adding a case record sharing rule into your logic for the record?